# Push notifications - Cordova FireBase Plugin on iOS - receiving only in console data message of notification

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova-plugin-firebase. On Android everything works fine, on iOS when I send push message via FireBase Console it appears only in xCode console:

```
Received data message: {
"collapse_key" = "myapp.id";
from = 932472342376;
notification =     {
    body = "Some notification";
    e = 1;
    sound = default;
    sound2 = default;
};
```

It appears only in console so I guess everything is setup correctly (like certificates, .plist file). How to force iOS to show this notification? I'm using latest version of xCode, Cordova and this plugin.
In app capabilities I also checked Background Modes - Remote Nofitications and Push Notifications but without changes.
It is also worth to say that this message comes only if app is opened, phone home button click indicates in console message: "Disconnected from FCM". Shouldn't it be connected instantly?

Comment: `It appears only in console` - do you see content of message you pushed in console?

Comment: @somerandomusername yes. And of course app is allowed to display notification.

Comment: on iOS app has to be minimised or closed for push notification to show. Did you test in closed or background mode ?

Comment: @somerandomusername of course. I closed and minimized app and nothing happened. After that I opened app and notification in console appeared immediately with my message I pushed via FireBase.

Comment: Tomorrow I will change xCode build system to legacy and check again, hope it will help.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: For iOS use cordova-plugin-fcm and for Android cordova-plugin-firebase. That is my workaround.